# rxjava2 execute service call on multithreading

Tags: multithreading, rx-java2

I am new to Rxjava2, basically i am trying to do some service call on multithread. I am getting multithread on some part but not all places where i expected.

e.g: I have attached sample unit test

```
import io.reactivex.Flowable;
import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers;
import lombok.Data;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class FlowableTest
{
    static Map<String, ClaimProcessor> mp = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        mp.putIfAbsent("vehicle", new VehicleClaimProcessor());
        mp.putIfAbsent("hospital", new HospitalClaimProcessor());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Claims claims = new Claims();
        claims.setClaimType("vehicle");
        Claims claims1 = new Claims();
        claims1.setClaimType("hospital");

        ClaimUser user1 = new ClaimUser();
        user1.setClaimList(Arrays.asList(claims, claims1));

        ClaimUser user2 = new ClaimUser();
        user2.setClaimList(Arrays.asList(claims, claims1));

        List<ClaimUser> userList = Arrays.asList(user1, user2);
        Flowable.fromIterable(userList)
                .flatMap(d -> Flowable.just(getClaimStatus(d)).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()))
                .map(d -> updateClaimStatus(d))
                //.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(d -> System.out.println("Processed"),
                err -> System.err.println(err.getMessage()));
    }

    private static ClaimUser updateClaimStatus(ClaimUser d)
    {
        //Update to DB
        return d;
    }

    private static ClaimUser getClaimStatus(ClaimUser d)
    {
        System.out.println(" ClaimUser Thread "+ Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return Flowable.fromIterable(d.getClaimList()).flatMap(dd -> {
            return Flowable.just(mp.get(dd.getClaimType()).processClaim(dd))
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .toList().map(ddd -> calculateOverallStatus(d))
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .blockingGet();

    }

    private static ClaimUser calculateOverallStatus(ClaimUser user)
    {
        //calculating overall status by all claims status
        user.setStatus("DOne");
        return user;
    }

    private interface ClaimProcessor
    {
        Claims processClaim(Claims claims);
    }

    private static class VehicleClaimProcessor implements ClaimProcessor
    {
        @Override public Claims processClaim(Claims claims)
        {
            System.out.println(" VehicleClaimProcessor Thread "+ Thread.currentThread().getName());
            return claims;
        }
    }

    private static class HospitalClaimProcessor implements ClaimProcessor
    {
        @Override public Claims processClaim(Claims claims)
        {
            System.out.println(" HospitalClaimProcessor Thread "+ Thread.currentThread().getName());
            return claims;
        }
    }
}

@Data class ClaimUser
{
    String name;
    List<Claims> claimList;
    String status;
}
```

and the output console is

```
ClaimUser Thread main
 VehicleClaimProcessor Thread RxCachedThreadScheduler-2
 HospitalClaimProcessor Thread RxCachedThreadScheduler-2
 ClaimUser Thread main
 Processed
 VehicleClaimProcessor Thread RxCachedThreadScheduler-3
 HospitalClaimProcessor Thread RxCachedThreadScheduler-3
 Processed
```

What i am expecting is - execute users on multi thread and execute claimprocessor on multithread and block for all the claimprocessor to complete and update the status.

can someone direct me right way to use it?

Comment: Change Flowable.just(getClaimStatus(d)) to Flowable.fromCallable(getClaimStatus(d))

Comment: Thanks @Dmitry, I will try and update the status.

Comment: If i use fromCallable nothing is getting printed.

Comment: Please give minimal example of code that reproduces the error you have. Currently it's hard to reproduce your issue with code you've given - there are some parts of it missing and some parts are irrelevant.

Comment: It works fine. Thanks @Dmitry and michalbrz